# regex: extract text blocks, defined beginning, undefined end

Tags: regex, vba, split

i have text like this:

```
Date: 01.02.2015 //<-stable format
something
something more
some random more
Date: 02.02.2015
something random
i dont know
```

so i have many such blocks. Starts with `Date...`  ends with next `Date...` start.
The text in the lines in the block could be anything, but not `Date...` format

I need an array at the end, with such blocks:

```
array[0] = "Date: 01.02.2015
    something
    something more
    some random more"

array[1] = "Date: 02.02.2015
    something random
    i dont know"
```

for now i add some unique splitter before `Date...` than split by the splitter.

Question: is it possible to get such blocks only by regex?

(i use VBA to parse the text, RegExp object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of split just match using

```
\bDate:\s\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}[\s\S]*?(?=\nDate:|$)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/77

Syntax explanation (from the linked site):

- **\b** assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
- **Date:** matches the characters **Date:** literally (case sensitive)
- **\s** matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
- **\d{1,2}**    matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- **.** matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
- **\d{1,2}**    matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- **.** matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
- **\d{4}**    matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) exactly 4 times
- **\s** matches any  whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
- **\S** matches any  non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
- ***?** Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) , what specified in previous brackets
- **?=** Positive Lookahead  - Assert that the following Regex  matches

  - **\nDate** Option 1

    - **\n** matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
    - **Date** matches the characters Date: literally (case sensitive)
  - **$**: Option 2 - $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)